# Nodejs Meanio module - init Command does not work

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

In the process of setting up MEAN Stack,

After installing meanio module on node 0.10.26, I can not pass through the command "mean init myApp".

```
   1. npm install -g "meanio'
   2. mean init myApp
   This always gives me "Prerequisite not installed: undefined".
```

Could you pls look at it ?

Regards
Ram

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved in this way: Go to [here](https://github.com/beknazar/mean "mean's github page") and do the procedures as shown in **quick install**, then repeat "mean init myApp"

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is neccessary to clear npm cache to make sure you really get the *latest* version you can use the `npm cache clear` command. There have been a few releases over the last few days so clearing npm cache might help you

Here is a summary of the install procedure.

```
sudo npm install -g meanio@latest
mean init <your app name>
cd <your app name> && npm install
grunt
```

Checkout http://www.mean.io/#!/docs for full documentation and make sure you meet all the prerequites.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a windows user and already installed Git on your machine, first add git to path in environment variable, then try it. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I too encountered the same issue.Though I have installed GIT on my mcahine, i was getting the error 
    "Prerequisite not installed: GIT"  while  running the command "mean init myApp".
This is because your command prompt doesnt know the path of GIT exe file.

I resolved this by adding the GIT path under Environment variables  as shown here http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/

Right-Click on My Computer
 Click Advanced System Settings link from the left side column
Click Environment Variables in the bottom of the window

Then under System Variables look for the path variable and click edit

Add the path to git's bin and cmd at the end of the string like this:
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

Please make sure that your give the correct path of GIT folder in the path under Environment variables.in your case it might not be same as mine.check where GIT files were created while installing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a recent version of Git installed. That error should read, "Prerequisite not installed: git". I'll take a look at why it says undefined instead.

As user3211907 meantioned, please take a look at http://www.mean.io/#!/docs for full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ram,
It is problem with git
install git and this problem should solve

To install git in Cent OS or any RedHat flavors use

> ## yum install git